# WebKit Implementation with c#

Tags: webkit

I implemented webKit into a c# app i'm using and it works great except for one problem. Let me give a background of what i'm using it for.

This is a program i've been building that will run multiple tests on multiple customer accounts, it loads each test into it's own dynamically created browser controls and such. However the issue i'm having is that some of the tests use Iframes which pass information in between the parent and child pages. These Iframes run a few ajax commands that show that they are loading, however it doesn't finish executing whatever scripts it needs to run. Is there something i need to change in the way I've added WebKit to my application or anyone else that has had any similar problems? These tests work in chrome and safari as well so i know webkit can do it, but for some reason it's not doing it for me.

Thanks for the help!